# Plot iterable classes with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, iterable

I'm having some problems with the plot of some iterable classes in Python. The idea is to use plotly to plot lines obtained from the iterator of a class. Here is an example of the class:

```
class example_class:
    ## Constructor
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.int_part = np.random.randint(0, 1023, size=n, dtype=np.uint16)
        self.dec_part = np.random.randint(0, 127, size=n, dtype=np.uint16)
        self.current = 0
        self.n = n

    ## Iterator
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    ## Next element during the iteration
    def __next__(self):
        if self.current < self.n:
            v = self.int_part[self.current] + self.dec_part[self.current]/100
            self.current += 1
            return v
        raise StopIteration

    ## Length
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n
```

There is not problem to plot just one instance of the class. For example, the following code generate a correct line plot

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

C = example_class(100)
fig = px.line(C)
fig.show()
```

[image]

But if I want to add more lines, like this

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

C = example_class(100)
D = example_class(100)
E = example_class(100)

fig = px.line(x=np.arange(0,100), y=[D,E])
fig.show()
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    fig.show()
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 3409, in show
    return pio.show(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py", line 403, in show
    renderers._perform_external_rendering(fig_dict, renderers_string=renderer, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py", line 340, in _perform_external_rendering
    renderer.render(fig_dict)
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_base_renderers.py", line 759, in render
    validate=False,
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_html.py", line 144, in to_html
    jdata = to_json_plotly(fig_dict.get("data", []))
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_json.py", line 143, in to_json_plotly
    json.dumps(plotly_object, cls=PlotlyJSONEncoder, **opts), _swap_json
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py", line 59, in encode
    encoded_o = super(PlotlyJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py", line 136, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
  File "/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type example_class is not JSON serializable
```

I tried many alternatives without success.

Anyone has an idea how to solve it?

Thanks!
José

Comment: Since C, D, and E are all random numbers, there is nothing here to suggest that D and E should or could share an x-axis. Typically, in a case like this, you might have an x-axis as simply 0-99, and plot D and E together using that shared "unit" axis.

Comment: Thanks, right!. I tried it, but I got a new error (the example was updated)

Comment: Looks like it can't be done. You should probably pass your values as lists, not these custom objects. Possibly you can provide a serializer that PX can use ... not sure though.

Comment: That's bad. My final goal is to represent the attributes int_part and dec_part has compact representations of integer sequences. So, we need to make it work with the custom class.

Comment: But if I'm not wrong, the method __next__ shows how to combine self.int_part and self.dec_part into one value. So, for line should be just one value

Comment: @JoséFuentes, no, `next` is ok. When you said "*to represent the attributes int_part and dec_part has compact representations of integer sequences*" - it sounded for me as representing those parts separately literally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building different figures (in particular `line`) `plotly` performs a lot of different checks which, among of others, include casting, sanitizing and, in case of generators/iterators, materializing those with constructing a new index (or so-called *placement*) - the sizes between them may diverge in such cases.
To handle/automate index preparation (for `x` axis) you can pass `pd.DataFrame` and specify the needed df columns for `y` axis:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(pd.DataFrame({'D': example_class(100), 
                            'E': example_class(100)}), y=['D', 'E'])
fig.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest, many thanks. Do you know if making a DataFrame will materialized the values stored in the objects of the example class or will it only save the references to the objects?

For context, I want to provide a way to plot time series using compact space. Thus, materialized the stored values as list, numpy arrays or any other structure different to the example class my increase the space to much

Comment: @JoséFuentes, those generators will be materialized anyway. In the above solution the dataframe is created on-the-fly and should be recognized by `plotly` as suitable data structure for further checks